# How to avoid re-compilatioin of c files?

Tags: c, compilation, linker, include

I created a library that I want to use in another part of my program, but I don't want to include it in the make file. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can built it before hand and link it at compile time using the `-l` command. Thank you.

Comment: The search terms you're looking for are "creating shared library <include OS here>".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Building-a-library.html

Just googled "building c libraries".

Comment: Does any downvoter care to explain how a google search term and an informative link doesn't answer the question "can someone point me in the right direction?"  Is the information inaccurate?  Poor search terms?  Unlikely to solve the OP's question?